How to align parts of a single equation?
I am trying to align parts of a single equation. What I have currently is:
\begin{align}
    x_i = \left(i-1\right) \Delta x   &  \left(i=1,2,\ldots,N\right) \label{eq6:x}
\end{align}


This just gives me a line with both sides of the '&' stuck together.
I have also tried using \tag{} for the right side of the equation but that doesn't allow me to show an equation number.

I have tried using \begin{flalign} but that aligns the first part completely to the left and the second part to the right.

I want the first part of the equation aligned to the center like any other equation and the second part to the right. Is there a way to do that while including the equation number?
Thank you.

you only appear to have a single equation so there is no alignment, just use \begin{equation}.  The align  family of environments are for multi-line displays with alignment between items on each line

If I use \begin{equation}, how do I get to align the two parts of the equation in the center and to the right respectively?

You should just use \begin{equation} x_i = (i - 1) \Delta x \qquad (i = 1, \dots, N) \end{equation}.

well that's a question (I would just do as Werner suggested) or you could put the right hand side into a \rlap so the left side stays centred, but never use align for a single line display, it can not possibly help.

"align" isn't aligning to the left or center or right.  It's aligning with respect to other lines within the same environment.  Thus, your question doesn't make sense.  If you want the left part to behave as if the right part isn't there, that's one thing.  If you have a nearby equation and you want this one's equal sign to align with that one's equal sign, then you might want \intertext, but some example code would help.

As explained also in the code below, I see no reason for moving the conditions on i to the far right. Anyway, you can achieve your goal with some devious tricks.
Note that \left and \right are useless and actually harmful, because they just add unwanted space.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

There's really no reason to have the equation centered and the
conditions to the far right. You can achieve the goal, though,
with
\begin{equation}\label{eq6:x}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}
   x_i = (i-1) \Delta x
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}
  \mathllap{(i=1,2,\dots,N)}\quad
\end{equation}
In my opinion, the conditions on $i$ are part of the equation,
so just
\begin{equation}\label{eq6:x-better}
  x_i = (i-1) \Delta x
  \qquad
  (i=1,2,\dots,N)
\end{equation}
would suffice. Note the omission of \verb|\left| and \verb|\right|
that in these cases do nothing useful and actually add unwanted
spacing. Also \verb|\ldots| should be \verb|\dots|.

\end{document}


